# Sound issue in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game using andEngine. I want to add a background sound for this game. I tried implementing sound,but sound is not getting played. pls help me out. Here is my code :

onLoadEngine()

```
return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
                new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera).setNeedsSound(true))
```

onLoadResources()

```
 Sound bgSound;
 SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
 this.bgSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this,              "bg.mid");
 bgSound.setLoopCount(-1);
 bgSound.play();
```

Comment: Is your sound file in the assets/gfx folder?

Comment: yes..it is in assets/gfx folder.

Comment: Move the setloopcount and play calls to onCreateScene

Comment: I moved it onCreateScene(),its not playing..

Comment: Last thing I can think of - Call createMusicFromAsset instead of createSoundFromAsset

Comment: I'll write it as an answer so others with the same problem would see the solution

Comment: yeah i got it after changing it to createMusicFromAsset..sound is playing now..Thanks..!!

Comment: Now i have another problem with this,when game is paused,I'm stopping the music and when game is resumed i'm trying to play music,its not getting played. any solution?

Comment: Are you using the Sound.pause() and Sound.resume() methods ? It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these 2 lines to the `onCreateScene()` method:

```
 bgSound.setLoopCount(-1);
 bgSound.play();
```

Also, call `SoundFactory.createMusicFromAsset` instead of `SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset`